# Dictionary Output Issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, output

I am trying to understand my below code a little better as far as why certain output is occurring.

```
stuff = {'purple':[0, 106, 506, 'SI', 'Lauren'], 'blue':'Cornflower', 'yo':'green'}
stuff_keys_sorted = sorted(stuff.keys())
print sorted(stuff.keys())
for k in stuff_keys_sorted:
    if type(stuff[k]) == type(['hello', 'goodbye']):
        for item in stuff[k]:
            print item
print k
```

The current output is:

```
0
106
506
SI
Lauren
yo
```

I understand why everything is happening up to the last line of " yo". Why would "yo" be the only option to print out, shouldn't my code just print any key in the dictionary?

Comment: You are printing the last key with `print k`, because it is *not part of the loop*. You'd need to *indent* it to be part of the loop.

Comment: Side note: It doesn't matter what you put inside the list here `type(['hello', 'goodbye'])`, you will always have `list` as the type. What are you actually trying to validate in that condition

Comment: What is `if type(stuff[k]) == type(['hello', 'goodbye']):` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the `print k` statement *outside* of the loop. The `for` loop is finished by the time Python reaches that statement, and only the last value for `k` is then printed.

If you wanted to print each key, you'd need to make it part of the loop:

```
for k in stuff_keys_sorted:
    # ...
    print k
```

Some other notes on your code:

- You don't have to call `.keys()`, `stuff_keys_sorted = sorted(stuff)` is enough to get a sorted sequence of dictionary keys.
- To test for a specific type, use `isinstance()` rather than using `type(..) == type(..)`:

  ```
  if isinstance(stuff[k], list):
  ```

  Even if you did need to use `type()`, you wouldn't need a list with contents; `type([])` would have been sufficient. But so would using `type(..) is list` (as the outcome of `type([])` is be `list`, and there is only one copy of every Python built-in type so using `is` is going to be a faster test).

Comment: Great thanks for the explanation that makes sense that it would just print "yo" since it is outside of the for loop! Also thanks for the tip about using if isinstance(stuff[k], list): that is way more efficient then just using type.